# Regex: Test if last slash exists or not in url after last word using javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I don't want to get everything after slash or before.

I want to check if last slash is present or not.

**For Example**

```
http://google.com/   --no
http://google.com/abc   --no
http://google.com/abc?c=1 --no
http://google.com/abc/ --yes
http://google.com/abc/?c=1 --yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/https?:\/\/[^\/]+\/.*?\/(?=\?|$)/igm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uW6cO2/3)

Comment: i modified question a little bit, sorry missed something crucial

Comment: i'm trying to make pathname based array. So i wan't path `/` to represent root. But i also want `/a`, `/a/`,`/a?...`,and `/a/?...` to be the same.